# Finding an object ID embedded in an array

Tags: mongodb

Challenge: I have two collections, schools and students. Students are separate documents in the students collections. School documents have an embedded array with all the students' Object ID attending the school. I am writing a query which will allow me to filter out documents which contain a sub array of students. For examples

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b49e31e4246501e057fa93"), 
    "name" : "school1", 
    "students" : [
        ObjectId("59b49d8de4246501e057fa77"), 
        ObjectId("59b49d9ae4246501e057fa7a"), 
        ObjectId("59b49da9e4246501e057fa7e")
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b49e86e4246501e057fa94"), 
    "name" : "school2", 
    "students" : [
        ObjectId("59b49d8de4246501e057fa76"), 
        ObjectId("59b49d9ae4246501e057fa7f"), 
        ObjectId("59b49da9e4246501e057fa80")
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b49ebfe4246501e057fa9e"), 
    "name" : "school3", 
    "students" : [
        ObjectId("59b49d8de4246501e057fa85"), 
        ObjectId("59b49d9ae4246501e057fa86"), 
        ObjectId("59b49da9e4246501e057fa77")
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b49eece4246501e057faac"), 
    "name" : "school4", 
    "students" : [
        ObjectId("59b49d8de4246501e057fa87"), 
        ObjectId("59b49d9ae4246501e057fa88"), 
        ObjectId("59b49da9e4246501e057fa89"), 
        ObjectId("59b49da9e4246501e057fa7e")
    ]
}
```

I want to filter out documents which contain the following array:

```
students: [ObjectID('59b49d8de4246501e057fa77'),ObjectID('59b49d8de4246501e057fa77')]
```

I have tried $elemMatch and $in but neither are working.

```
db.schools.find({students: {$in : ['59b49d8de4246501e057fa77','59b49d9ae4246501e057fa7a']}})
```

Please help.

Comment: They need to be `ObjectId` and not "strings" if they are in fact `ObjectId`. As in `db.schools.find({students: {$in : [ObjectId('59b49d8de4246501e057fa77'),ObjectId('59b49d9ae4246501e057fa7a')] } })`. It does not help that your whole question is abstract. If you have a real problem, then "show your real data" so we know what you really mean. Abstract questions are not used to solve basic issues, since the problem in the first place is your own misinterpretation.

Comment: I have updated the post with actual data from the DB.

Comment: Okay then, just as I said pass `ObjectId` cast values to `$in`, and that selects the documents with those matching entries. What is the problem?

Comment: Thank you. Also, here is the correct command:

db.sections.find({entities: {$in : [ObjectId('59b49d8de4246501e057fa77'),ObjectId('59b49d9ae4246501e057fa7a')]}})

I had to encapsulate the Id's with 'ObjectId()'